# Existence of certain subsemigroups of $C(K, K)$ for compact Hausdorff spaces $K$

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. I'm wondering: Does there always exist a subset $J \subseteq C(K, K)$ such that:

- $J$ is closed under composition,
- there is an element $f \in C(K)$ such that the map $J\rightarrow C(K)$, $g \mapsto f\circ g$ is bijective.

If not, how does a possible counterexample look like?

Comment: What about $J=C(K,K)$ and $f$ the identity?

Comment: I want the function $f$ to be an element of $C(K)$. Since $K$ is not necessarily a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ there might be no identity in $C(K)$

Comment: So to clarify, $C(K)$ means $C(K, \mathbb{C})$?

Answer (score 1):

Fix any $f \in C(K)$.  Then the range $f(K)$ is compact, so there is some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ which is not in the range of $f$.  The constant function $z_0$ is thus not of the form $f \circ g$ for any $g \in C(K,K)$, so your map $J \to C(K)$ cannot be surjective, no matter what $J$ is.

Is there something missing from the statement of the problem?